# How to open branch view in smart git 21.2, to see the branch merging line and all that, not just one straight line

Tags: smartgit

Is there setting in smartgit 21.2 to display all the branch line, not just one straight line?
[image: Now it looks like this, only with one straight line]

Comment: I would assume you need to change some sort of filter?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am pretty new to both git and smartgit, I tried open a lot settings to find, but can't seem to find any where

Comment: In the Log, Branches view you can toggle which branches to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the Log tab, but this worked for version 21.2.4 #18150.

Look for the Branches tab and select the branches you want to see

[image]

You can adjust the coloring in the Graph tab settings (top right corner).

[image]

Comment: wow haha thank you, it has been so long, that was during my intern, thanks anyway~